# When analyzing a particle moving at Kepler speed, √(GM/R) in a planetary magnetic field, do we need to convert it to angular speed, √(GM/R^3)?

Tags: astrophysics, stellar-astrophysics, planetary-science, units, high-energy-astrophysics

A charged particle is moving in a planetary magnetic field, in a spherical polar coordinates which is corotating with the magnetic field. To solve the equations of motion numerically what would be the initial azimuthal speed $\frac{d\phi}{dt}$, if the particle initially moving with the Kepler speed,$\sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$ along the equatorial in the co rotational direction? Do we need convert the keppler speed into the corresponding angular speed, $\sqrt{\frac{GM}{R^3}}$ as the azimuthal speed is in radian/s while the kepler speed is in m/s? The same question goes what if I only know the initial speed in km/s, say 20km/s how would I input this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$d\phi/dt$ is an angular speed, so yes you should set this to be an angular speed. You say the coordinate system co-rotates with the magnetic field, so you should also apply any offset for this.

If the initial speed is 20 km/s, then the angular speed in radians/s is given by 20,000 divided by the radial coordinate in metres.

Comment: Thank you. That was simple and clear response. As regard to the coordinate, its centre is taken to be centre of the planet i.e. the magnetic field.

Comment: @LunthangPeter I assumed that. The issue is the co-rotating coordinate system. Your angular velocity should be with respect to the magnetic field, not with respect to a non-rotating frame.

Comment: Yes. Point Noted.